# To enable or disable the select component on button click in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using  select component 2 times for selecting the timings and i also added icon as a suffix to make action as **add** and **cancel**.As shown in below image

[image]

when i click the cancel icon then it is changing to add icon as shown in below image.
[image]

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
 <mat-form-field class="no-line time">
                <mat-select  [(value)]="selectmonmor">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let mondaymorning of mondaymornings"  [value]="mondaymorning.value">
                    {{mondaymorning.viewValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>

              <mat-form-field  class="no-line time">
                  <mat-select [(value)]="selectmoneve">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let mondayevening of mondayevenings" [value]="mondayevening.value">
                      {{mondayevening.viewValue}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>

  </mat-form-field>
   <button  mat-button  matSuffix mat-icon-button >
          <mat-icon (click)="toggleIcon()">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

**TS**

```
  public icon = 'highlight_off';

   public toggleIcon() {
   if (this.icon === 'highlight_off') {
     this.icon = 'add_circle_outline';
   } else {
     this.icon = 'highlight_off';
     }
   }
```

Here on clicking the icon i,e `<mat-icon (click)="toggleIcon()">{{icon}}</mat-icon>` the cancel icon(i,e **highlight_off**) it changing to add icon (i,e **add_circle_outline**) Now i need to disable the 2 dropdown(**select** components) on clicking the cancel icon then the icon will be changed to **add**, on clicking **add** select component as to be enabled.On surfing i got [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-xdnxes?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) link too

but here enable/disable actions are performing by 2 separate button using 2 click function, but i need it perform by only one icon.How can i do it?

Comment: How this question has 2 votes and 5 views. Something is fishy

Comment: Sorry my  colleagues given the vote, we are working on the same issue.@TamoDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-k9eyun)

HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    Angular Material 2 App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="basic-container">

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Sample" [disabled]="selectDisabled">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of [1, 2, 3, 4]" [value]="opt">
                Option {{ opt }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button (click)="selectDisabled = !selectDisabled" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon >{{selectDisabled?'add': 'cancel'}}</mat-icon>
  </button>
    <pre>disabled: {{ selectDisabled }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for this question, I need to apply for many select components.How can i change the function `{{selectDisabled?'add': 'cancel'` name so that it won't invoke other select components.

Comment: yes use *ngFor and maintain index for each select element;

Comment: I got it,Thank you.